# SQL statement to select join multiple fields from different table?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a sql statement that joins attribute from different tables but I am having confusion on how to call it. I'll explain the tables first.

[image: Table : Machine and MeterReading]

First table is machine with some machine 
The second table contain some meter reading description.

[image: Table : meterReadingMachine and Actual Reading]

In third table, ID column of table Machine and MeterReading are used as foreign key to indicate the types of meter readings available to machines. One machines can have multiple meter reading descriptions.

Table 4 use the ID of table meterreadingMachine and store the reading for particular machine and its meterreading description.

Now I want to select all Machines using ID (for example `select * from meterreadingMachine WHERE MachineID = 1`) and list the actualreading for all the machine ID= 1  from table actual reading.

Comment: You are looking for a JOIN

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the pretty awesome possibility called `JOIN`:

```
    SELECT M.*
          ,mR.*
          ,AR.actualreading
      FROM Maschine M
INNER JOIN meterReadingMachine  mRM
        ON mRM.machineid            = M.maschineID
INNER JOIN meterReading mR
        ON mR.meterreadingid        = mRM.meterreadingid
INNER JOIN ActualReading AR
        ON AR.meterreadingmachineid = mRM.meterreadingmachineid
     WHERE M.MachineID = 1
```

Comment: awesome dude, this gives the perfect output. Thank you.